# Android will not read/write file

Tags: java, android, libgdx, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read the file,

```
/storage/emulated/0/proj/Assets/Images/Screens/Title.png
```

I can clearly see the file exists, I can navigate to the file, I can open the file, I verified that the code loads that file, yet when running the project I receive,

```
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: /storage/emulated/0/proj/Assets/Images/Screens/Title.png
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/proj/Assets/Images/Screens/Title.png
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
03-08 15:34:44.415 22192 22209 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 13 more
```

Permissions are as follows,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the code (consolidated from multiple classes)

```
public static File getBaseDirectory() { 
    return Gdx.files.external("proj").file();
}

private static File getAssetsDirectory() {
    File dir = new File(FileUtils.getBaseDirectory(), "Assets");
    dir.mkdirs();
    return dir;
}

private static File getImagesDirectory() {
    File dir = new File(getAssetsDirectory(), "Images");
    dir.mkdirs();
    return dir;
}

private static File getScreensDirectory() {
    File dir = new File(getImagesDirectory(), "Screens");
    dir.mkdirs();
    return dir;
}

public static Texture getScreen(String name) {
    File f = new File(getScreensDirectory(), name);
    return new Texture(f.getAbsolutePath()); //<--where it is failing
}
```

Details,

```
Phone: Nexus 5
Android Version: 6.0
compileSdkVersion: 21
targetSdkVersion: 21
```

My own code that writes the log file writes to,

```
/storage/emulated/0/proj/log.txt
```

without errors or issues. The logger class I wrote obtains the location from the same set of methods as the code causing issues.

File.exists() reads that it does exist.

Why is Android throwing a java.io.FileNotFoundException when it does in fact exist?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Also, what is the `targetSdkVersion` of your app?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the compileSdkVersion but could not find targetSdkVersion, where would I locate that info? Sorry, I am very new at both using libgdx and Android development.

Comment: need some code.  are you specifying `file://` before the path?

Comment: Just becuase it exists, it doesn't mean you can read the file. Try checking the permissions. Also did you use any of the File APIs to confirm that you can interact with the file? Like File.exists() ?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, `targetSdkVersion` usually is in your `build.gradle` file. Otherwise, look for a `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest and an `android:targetSdkVersion` attribute on there.

Comment: @CommonsWare added to post. 21

Comment: OK, that seems fine. If your `targetSdkVersion` was 23 or higher, you would need to have additional code to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime. I would use breakpoints or logging to confirm that the methods you are using are returning what you think that they are returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libgdx Texture(String) does not work as I thought on Android, this issue was resolved by changing,

```
public static Texture getScreen(String name) {
    File f = new File(getScreensDirectory(), name);
    return new Texture(f.getAbsolutePath()); //<--where it is failing
}
```

to,

```
public static Texture getScreen(String name) {
    File f = new File(getScreensDirectory(), name);
    return new Texture(Gdx.files.absolute(f.getAbsolutePath())); //<--where it was failing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (the `com.badlogic.gdx` stuff is yours, right?) is trying to open the file using [AssetManager.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29). That method is for opening files packaged as *assets in your APK*. So the exception is saying that your path does not exist in your APK's asset folder.

To open a file with a direct path, just use `new FileInputStream(path)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with PNG's I have minified, and then when I try to load them, libgdx died on me with the same file not found error.

The libgdx library has problems with some minified PNG's, so if your PNG is compressed to 8bit, try with the original one.